# No test under python unittest in visual studio 2019

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, python-unittest, visual-studio-2019

I have an existing python project in visual studio 2019 (Version16.3.9) containing unit test created for unittest.py under visual studio 2017. I already configered the project for unittest, because this is needed in visual studio 2019:

[image]

But there are no unit tests shown.

But I got the following error:

```
   File "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py", line 17, in <module>
    tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs = parse_args()
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\__main__.py", line 81, in parse_args
    subsub = add_subparser(cmdname, toolname, subsubs)
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\__main__.py", line 26, in pytest_add_cli_subparser
    from . import pytest
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\pytest\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._discovery import discover
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\pytest\_discovery.py", line 31, in <module>
    patch_translate_non_printable()
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\pytest\_discovery.py", line 15, in patch_translate_non_printable
    translate_non_printable =  getattr(_pytest.compat, "_translate_non_printable")
AttributeError: module '_pytest.compat' has no attribute '_translate_non_printable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your output windows under "Tests" for the arguments passed to run_adapter.py, and make sure **discover unittest** there?

example

```
xxx\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT CORPORATION\PYTHON\16.0.0\PythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover unittest --output-file xx\Local\Temp\tmpF743.tmp -- . test*.py
```

Also is pytest installed in your environment? If so which version?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The arguments for the run_adapter.py are:
xxx\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover unittest --output-file xxx\Local\Temp\tmp7C07.tmp -- . *_tests.py

Comment: Interesting. Then i'm assuming you also have pytest in your environment but for some reason it doesn't have _pytest.compat.  You could try to update your pytest version to the latest. Failing that you could try editing ```C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\__main__.py``` the  TOOLS list and remove pytest