# Visual Studio 2019 does not find python tests (pytest or unittest)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, python-unittest

I just started a Django project with Visual Studio 2019 (*v 16.4.3*) to get familiar with it and I am seeing that the unit tests are not being discovered.

Visual Studio allows to add a unittest python file, that contains a file that should fail when run, so I am pretty sure that it should be discoverable:

```py
import unittest

class Test_test_1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_A(self):
        self.fail("Not implemented")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I also tried to change the settings in *Project/Properties* and tried with both pytest and unittest, but the result is the same:

[image]
*(of course clicking "Run All" doesn't discover anything)*

Running `python manage.py test` finds 0 tests as well:

[image]

Is it a known Visual Studio problem?
Or am I placing the files in the wrong path?
Any hint about what I am doing wrong here?

p.s. 
I saw [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993126/no-test-under-python-unittest-in-visual-studio-2019) about this, but this guy was getting an error. I just get nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, reopening Visual Studio after having installed PyCharm prompted a message about *pytest* not being installed in the system (it was installed, I am sure of it). Clicking on the action in the message reinstalled it and, after rebuilding the project, the tests were discovered:

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, though nothing to do with PyCharm. Selecting `pytest` framework, then restarting VS2019, and "reinstalling" pytest fixed the issue.